# JIRA GitHub Integration in an online hosted jira solution

Tags: github, integration, jira, hosted

I know there is a github jira plugin, which is a .jar https://github.com/atlassian/jira-github-connector-plugin , how do I add this to an online hosted jira solution.

Basically we'd like to see commit activity, update time in jira tickets with a github commit message and the "source" tab should show github project rather than the default svn that jira provides.

Regards,
Noj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this question today while searching, figured I would add in the link from Jira.  Must not have been available at the time this question was asked.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRASTUDIO/Integrating+GitHub+with+JIRA+Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about JIRA Studio, they do not support any plugins except the ones they provide:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRASTUDIO/JIRA+Studio+Plugin+Policy